# how to detect events in a html page embedded inside another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am working on a website which has an html page embedded inside the html page using iframe tag.

I need to capture an event in the inner html page (when a login event takes place) from the outer html page. How can i do that?

Comment: What do you know about the html page within the iFrame? do you know what function is called when logging in?

Comment: @nayish yeah. a function wa_login is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on the same domain, I'm not sure it will work for the content from another domain though:

```
window.frames[0].document.getElementById("myElementId").onclick = function(){
        alert("Testing...")
}
```

assume that the element with an id `myElementId` is in the iframe.